# Putting wrapper components in react router switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I need to create a layout that only applies to certain routes. However, when I use a Switch and separate the routes that need alternate layouts, if I try to visit a page that doesn't exist it just takes me to the layout with nothing inside of it. Here is the sample code.

```js
<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={SampleComponent} />
    <TokenLayout>
        <Route path="/some-random-component" component={SomeRandomComponent} />
    </TokenLayout>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

the `NotFound` component never renders, instead it renders the `TokenLayout` with no children.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue here is that the [`Switch`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch) component "Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location." The official docs don't make it *overtly* clear that `Route` (*and variations of*) and `Redirect` are the only valid children of the `Switch` component. When a non-route or non-redirect component is hit, route matching stops and *that* component is returned and rendered. What happens next is that the nested route rendering `SomeRandomComponent` is inclusively matched just as if it would be by the router not inside a `Switch`.

## Solution

Refactor the code to render the `TokenLayout` component *inside* the route.

Here are a few suggestions:

- Create a wrapper component

  ```
    const TokenLayoutWrapper = props => (
      <TokenLayout>
        <SomeRandomComponent {...props} />
      </TokenLayout>
    );
  ```

  ...

  ```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={SampleComponent} />
      <Route path="/some-random-component" component={TokenLayoutWrapper} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  ```
- Create a Higher Order Component

  ```
    const withTokenLayout = Component => props => (
      <TokenLayout>
        <Component {...props} />
      </TokenLayout>
    );
  ```

  Decorate the `SomeRandomComponent` component export:

  ```
    export default withTokenLayout(SomeRandomComponent);
  ```

  ...

  ```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={SampleComponent} />
      <Route path="/some-random-component" component={SomeRandomComponent} />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  ```
- Just wrap `SomeRandomComponent` in an inline function using the `render` prop, pass the route props through to `SomeRandomComponent`.

  ```
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={SampleComponent} />
      <Route
        path="/some-random-component"
        render={props => (
          <TokenLayout>
            <SomeRandomComponent {...props} />
          </TokenLayout>
        )}
      />
      <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  ```

Comment: This helped me come up with my solution thanks! I followed the suggestion you gave on decorating the export.